# LinearSVC in Scikit-learn is slow when cost of making mistakes is large

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm working through the ISLR book exercises (1st ed) but coding up the problems in Python.

Under the SVM section, there is a problem on training a classifier for the [OJ data set](https://github.com/gchoi/Dataset/blob/master/oj.csv). The number of training samples is 800 and I have around 22 columns (features) after doing one-hot encoding.

When I train an SVM using LinearSVC, the training is very fast if C, the cost parameter which controls the number of support vectors, is low. Smaller C means larger number of support vectors. However, when C is large, say 10 which is what the book instructs, the training isn't finished even after 30 minutes (It's still running as I type).

If I understand the algorithm correctly, this is expected behavior, correct? This is because if there are only a few support vectors, there are more ways to choose which training points to be support vectors...

Is there an alternative to speed-up the code? Here's a minimum working example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

oj = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/makbigc/ISLR/blob/master/datasets/OJ.csv?raw=TRUE", index_col=0)
oj.Store7 = oj.Store7.map({"No":0, "Yes":1})

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

encodedStoreID = enc.fit_transform(oj[["StoreID"]])
oj[["StoreID_1","StoreID_2","StoreID_3","StoreID_4"]] = encodedStoreID[:,:-1].toarray()

X = oj.loc[:,oj.columns.isin(['Purchase','StoreID','STORE']) == False]
y = oj.loc[:,"Purchase"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=800/X.shape[0], random_state=42)
model = LinearSVC(C=10, random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: You should ask this on one of the machine learning Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the following [class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html):

> class sklearn.svm.LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge', *,
> dual='warn', tol=0.0001, C=1.0, multi_class='ovr', fit_intercept=True,
> intercept_scaling=1, class_weight=None, verbose=0, random_state=None,
> max_iter=1000)[source]

and C:

> C: Regularization parameter. The strength of the
> regularization is inversely proportional to C. Must be strictly
> positive.

Followed by this post:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/4943/intuition-for-the-regularization-parameter-in-svm:

> So, intuitively, as C grows larger the less the wrongly
> classified examples are allowed (or the highest the price the pay in
> the loss function). Then when C tends to infinite the solution
> tends to the hard-margin (allow no miss-classification). When C
> tends to 0 (without being 0) the more the miss-classifications are
> allowed.

In other words:
The bigger the C is, the more accurate the class tries to optimize and the more time you need.